# How many connections does the client make to the server in 1 minute?

Tags: minecraft-java-edition, minecraft-java-edition-server, server-administration, hosting

If I have a script that checks for x connections every x minutes and blocks IP's after x connections will it stop Minecraft servers from working properly?

How many connections does the Minecraft client make to the server in one minute?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends, if you are connected and playing it only has one persistent connection. If you are on your server selection screen it will have a temporary connection once per refresh of the server selection screen.

So I guess a good estimate would be 2 + however many times you think someone will hit refresh on their server selection screen on average.

Comment: Alright. Sounds good. Don't think anyone will hit refresh 50 times